# How to check programmatically if hotspot is enabled or disabled?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect WiFi tethering state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065592/how-to-detect-wifi-tethering-state)

I need to check if hotspot is on or not on my device through my app?

Answer (score 16):

Code:
**Java**

```
Method method = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getWifiApState");
method.setAccessible(true);
int actualState = (Integer) method.invoke(wifiManager, (Object[]) null);
```

Code:
**Kotlin**

```
    fun getHotspotState(): String {
    val wifiManager =
        applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    val method: Method = wifiManager.javaClass.getMethod(
        "getWifiApState"
    )
    method.isAccessible = true
    val invoke = method.invoke(wifiManager)
    println(invoke)
    return invoke.toString();
}
```

the actual state should be:

```
public static int AP_STATE_DISABLING = 10;
public static int AP_STATE_DISABLED = 11;
public static int AP_STATE_ENABLING = 12;
public static int AP_STATE_ENABLED = 13;
public static int AP_STATE_FAILED = 14;
```

[WifiManger source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java#L197)

hope this might be help you!