# How to check WiFi hotspot(AP) is enabled an Android app

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, wifi, hotspot

I am making an Android app that will communicate via Bluetooth with other devices. These devices need to check WiFi hotspot. How can I, from inside the app, check if the phone is an WiFi hotspot?

I don't need to turn hotspot on from the application, just check if it has so I can tell the user to turn it on manually to be able to use the app.

EDIT:
I just realized the question is not really correct.

The phone with the app I am developing connects to internet via wifi. Then it needs to share internet with other devices via Bluetooth. The answers here worked fine to check if WiFi hotspot is on. But I need to check if it can share internet via Bluetooth with other devices.

The phone gets internet via wifi, but the devices have to get internet via Bluetooth.

Comment: @SaTech, I don't think that you know what the asker needs. Please, not decide instead of him. You didn't understand a question.

Comment: The thing is that the other device need to use the internet 
through the phone. If the phone is not a hotspot, the device can't use internet and the app will not work.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401108/how-to-check-programmatically-if-hotspot-is-enabled-or-disabled

Comment: @Rudy, duplicate of duplicate :-)

Comment: this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065592/how-to-detect-wifi-tethering-state :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. However, I realized the question was not really correct. I edited the original post accordingly.