# How can I get in my app when hostspot state changed?

Tags: android, hotspot

I have a prototype Android app that is listening mobile function state continuously like Hotspot. For bluetooth detect, I am using `registerContentObserver()` to get the latest state and it will notify me in custom `ContentObserver`.

So for Hotspot,

1. How can I detect hotspot on/off
2. Check any device connected through hotspot or not

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check if hotspot is enabled or not

```
Method method = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getWifiApState");
    method.setAccessible(true);
    int actualState = (Integer) method.invoke(wifiManager, (Object[]) null);
```

Different States

```
public static int AP_STATE_DISABLING = 10;
public static int AP_STATE_DISABLED = 11;
public static int AP_STATE_ENABLING = 12;
public static int AP_STATE_ENABLED = 13;
public static int AP_STATE_FAILED = 14;
```

For detecting clients you can use 
`android.net.wifi.WIFI_HOTSPOT_CLIENTS_CHANGED` broadcast receiver.

Comment: After goggling I posted question on SO. This answer is already posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14405339/2078074).