# How do i check if the device opened a Hotspot?

Tags: android

I am very new to stackoverflow so I am trying to keep my question short and intelligible. And im sorry for my bad english :P

In my App, im trying to get the network status of my phone when it made a hotspot. I know how to get the Wifi status or the Mobile status for example, but in what Status is my smartphone if it opened a Hotspot?

What I got until now is how to check if the device got WIFI on, and that's how:

```
connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

**So the question is how do I check if the device opened a Hotspot or not?**

Best Regards, Alex

Comment: The answer lies in using the undocumented `WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLED` will tell you that the hotspot was opened, also the intent `WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` is the key to your answer!

Comment: Can you tell me an example of how a method that returns TRUE if the device opened a hotspot would look like? I dont really know how this would look like, I also cant find anything like that via Google.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`WifiManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html). Retrieve an instance using:

```
WifiManager wmgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
```

and then, using `wmgr.getConnectionInfo()`, you can get information on the current connection  to a hotspot.

Comment: thanks for the fast response! But what do I get returned if the device im on opened a hotspot?

Comment: I believe you will get a [`WifiInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html) object. I believe if it's null that means you're not connected to a hotspot.

Comment: The OP is asking how to detect if the device has activated a WiFi tethering hotspot.. :)

Comment: Oh... keyword "tethering" makes all the difference. OP was not clear with what he wanted to do; don't see how that justifies a downvote. :(

Comment: A quick search turned up [some results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065592/how-to-detect-wifi-tethering-state)