# How to find the WiFi tethering state through ADB?

Tags: android, adb, wifimanager, tethering

I was just wondering how to find the state of Wifi tethering through ADB.

Although, there are some options to find the state through WifiManager() as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007361/is-there-a-way-to-check-whether-tethering-is-active), I just want to know if its possible through ADB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `adb shell dumpsys wifi` and search for `curState=TetheredState`
to check wifi tethering is enabled.

Comment: How to parse properly this output ? This is not JSON

Answer (score 1):

Command `adb shell dumpsys wifi` didn't work for me.

So, here is another solution:

1. Run `adb shell dumpsys connectivity`
2. Search for interface pattern `tetherableWifiRegexs:`
3. Use that regex pattern to search for enabled interfaces. Example: `ap\d - TetheredState`
4. If there is a match, WiFi tethering is on

---

Also here is my Python implementation:

```py
import re
import subprocess
import time

def run_adb(command):
    res = subprocess.run(['adb'] + command.split(), capture_output=True)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return res

def is_wifi_hotspot_enabled():
    output = run_adb('shell dumpsys connectivity').stdout.decode()

    pattern = 'ap\d'
    if match := re.search('tetherableWifiRegexs: \[(.*)\]', output):
        pattern = match.group(1)

    match = re.search(f'{pattern} - TetheredState', output)
    return (match is not None)
```

Answer (score 1):

"shell dumpsys connectivit"

[image]

```
wlan0 - TetheredState - lastError = 0
wlan0 - AvailableState - lastError = 0
```